# Localization web api odata best practices?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, asp.net-web-api

I am working with ASP.NET WebApi OData, working fine. I did customize routing, strongly typed output json result.

I need to localize this Odata feed, looking best practices localization web api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the HTTP Accept-Language Header to define the user language.
Otherwise you question is a little broad..